# apache drill - AssertionError: Relational expression

Tags: mysql, apache-drill

running apache-drill-1.14.0

tested this query on mysql and got result in 0.02 sec

running the query in drill cli fails with AssertionError

**Query:**

product_id is BIGINT

```
  SELECT test50.customername, test50.color, test50.age, test50.city,  
  test50.product_id, test50.price FROM myplugin.sampler.test50 JOIN 
  myplugin.sampler.test52 ON test50.product_id = test52.product_id WHERE 
  test50.product_id = 759216 GROUP BY test50.customername, test50.color,
  test50.age, test50.city, test50.product_id, test50.price ORDER BY
  test50.customername;
```

**Error:**

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AssertionError: Relational expression
rel#873:DrillFilterRel.JDBC.myplugin.ANY([]).
[](input=rel#83:JdbcTableScan.JDBC.myplugin.ANY([]).[](table=[myplugin, 
sampler, test50]),condition=OR(=($18, 759216), =($18, 494636))) has  
calling-convention JDBC.myplugin but does not implement the required interface 
'interface org.apache.calcite.adapter.jdbc.JdbcRel' of that convention
```

need help if I need some extra configuration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check on current master? Looks like it was fixed in [DRILL-6850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6850).

Comment: hi https://drill.apache.org/docs/compiling-drill-from-source/ is this right method to check on current master, and doing `git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/drill.git` gives `fatal: repository 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/drill.git/' not found`

Comment: `0: jdbc:drill:> SELECT * FROM myplugin.sampler.test50 a JOIN myplugin.sampler.test52 b ON a.product_id = b.product_id WHERE b.product_id = 759216;` does WHERE condition are supported in JOIN getting `Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AssertionError: Relational expression`

Comment: Looks like you are sill using the old drillbit. Is it embedded or distributed mode? You can verify the version with `select * from sys.version;`

Comment: Hi it is running in distributed mode

select * from sys.version; in CLI gave 

version - 1.14.0
commit_id - 0508a128853ce796ca7e99e13008e49442f83147
commit_message - [maven-release-plugin] prepare release drill-1.14.0

Comment: @ManojKumar, please try `git clone git@github.com:apache/drill.git` or `git clone https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/drill.git`, docs on the site are obsolete.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, i was able to get current master and it is working fine.